# Python vectorised minimisation (i.e multiple data realisations)

Tags: python, optimization, vectorization, minimization

Suppose I have a (multivariate) function

```
f(x,data)
```

that I want to minimise, where `x` is the parameter vector. Ordinarily in Python I could do something like this:

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(f, x0, args=my_data)
```

However, suppose I now want to do this repeatedly, for lots of different realisations of `my_data` (this is for some statistical simulations so I need lots of realisations to study the behaviour of test statistics and so on).

I could do it in a big loop, but this is really slow if I have tens of thousands, up to millions, of data realisations.

So, I am wondering if there is some clever way to vectorise this rather than using a loop. I have one vague idea; say I have `N` data realisations and `p` parameters. I could make an enormous combined function with `N*p` parameters, which accepts a data vector of size `N`, and finds the minimum of this giant function all at once, where the global minimum of this giant function minimises all the individual functions simultaneously.

However this sounds like a difficult problem for most multivariate minimisers to handle. Yet, the structure of the problem is fairly simple, since each block of `p` parameters can be minimised entirely independently. So, I wonder, is there an algorithm in `scipy` or somewhere that can make use of this known dependency structure between the parameters? Or, if not, is there some other smart way to achieve a speedy minimisation of the same function repeatedly?

Comment: One big model is usually not a good idea (solve time is not linear in the variables). You could run several data sets in parallel.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that too. All three approaches could be combined, i.e. a parallelised loop over some "block" models. Some combination of that might be the most efficient. But choosing the right algorithm to minimise each "block" could make a big difference, since, in principle, the solve time *should* be linear in the variables, given the independence structure. Surely some minimizers know how to use that information? If I had enough RAM I could make an (M^p)*N array, with some number of grid points M per dimension, and then just run np.min on it and it would be super fast.

Comment: I remember some solvers could detect a staircase structure and exploit that using some decomposition. I don't know any current solvers doing something like this. If fixed setup cost is high then combining a small number of data sets can help (I have done this with some DEA models which are often very small).